# How to take photo and save it at the same time (swift3)

Tags: ios, swift, swift3, save, photo

Right now my code has 1 view, 1 button, and 1 image view. Currently the code takes the photo and places on the uniimageview. How can I write the code so that every time the photo is snap it will be saved to the photo gallery. I have already updated the plist settings.

```
 import UIKit
import AVFoundation

class ViewController: UIViewController,AVCapturePhotoCaptureDelegate  {

var captureSesssion : AVCaptureSession!
var cameraOutput : AVCapturePhotoOutput!
var previewLayer : AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer!

@IBOutlet weak var capturedImage: UIImageView!
@IBOutlet weak var previewView: UIView!

override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    captureSesssion = AVCaptureSession()
    captureSesssion.sessionPreset = AVCaptureSessionPresetPhoto
    cameraOutput = AVCapturePhotoOutput()

    let device = AVCaptureDevice.defaultDevice(withMediaType: AVMediaTypeVideo)

    if let input = try? AVCaptureDeviceInput(device: device) {
        if (captureSesssion.canAddInput(input)) {
            captureSesssion.addInput(input)
            if (captureSesssion.canAddOutput(cameraOutput)) {
                captureSesssion.addOutput(cameraOutput)
                previewLayer = AVCaptureVideoPreviewLayer(session: captureSesssion)
                previewLayer.frame = previewView.bounds
                previewView.layer.addSublayer(previewLayer)
                captureSesssion.startRunning()
            }
        } else {
            print("issue here : captureSesssion.canAddInput")
        }
    } else {
        print("some problem here")
    }
}

// Take picture button
@IBAction func didPressTakePhoto(_ sender: UIButton) {
    let settings = AVCapturePhotoSettings()
    let previewPixelType = settings.availablePreviewPhotoPixelFormatTypes.first!
    let previewFormat = [
        kCVPixelBufferPixelFormatTypeKey as String: previewPixelType,
        kCVPixelBufferWidthKey as String: 160,
        kCVPixelBufferHeightKey as String: 160
    ]
    settings.previewPhotoFormat = previewFormat
    cameraOutput.capturePhoto(with: settings, delegate: self)

}

// callBack from take picture
func capture(_ captureOutput: AVCapturePhotoOutput,  didFinishProcessingPhotoSampleBuffer photoSampleBuffer: CMSampleBuffer?,  previewPhotoSampleBuffer: CMSampleBuffer?, resolvedSettings:  AVCaptureResolvedPhotoSettings, bracketSettings:   AVCaptureBracketedStillImageSettings?, error: Error?) {

    if let error = error {
        print("error occure : \(error.localizedDescription)")
    }

    if  let sampleBuffer = photoSampleBuffer,
        let previewBuffer = previewPhotoSampleBuffer,
        let dataImage =  AVCapturePhotoOutput.jpegPhotoDataRepresentation(forJPEGSampleBuffer:  sampleBuffer, previewPhotoSampleBuffer: previewBuffer) {
        print(UIImage(data: dataImage)?.size as Any)

        let dataProvider = CGDataProvider(data: dataImage as CFData)
        let cgImageRef: CGImage! = CGImage(jpegDataProviderSource: dataProvider!, decode: nil, shouldInterpolate: true, intent: .defaultIntent)
        let image = UIImage(cgImage: cgImageRef, scale: 1.0, orientation: UIImageOrientation.right)

        self.capturedImage.image = image
    } else {
        print("some error here")
    }
}

// This method you can use somewhere you need to know camera permission   state
func askPermission() {
    print("here")
    let cameraPermissionStatus =  AVCaptureDevice.authorizationStatus(forMediaType: AVMediaTypeVideo)

    switch cameraPermissionStatus {
    case .authorized:
        print("Already Authorized")
    case .denied:
        print("denied")

        let alert = UIAlertController(title: "Sorry :(" , message: "But  could you please grant permission for camera within device settings",  preferredStyle: .alert)
        let action = UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: .cancel,  handler: nil)
        alert.addAction(action)
        present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)

    case .restricted:
        print("restricted")
    default:
        AVCaptureDevice.requestAccess(forMediaType: AVMediaTypeVideo, completionHandler: {
            [weak self]
            (granted :Bool) -> Void in

            if granted == true {
                // User granted
                print("User granted")
                DispatchQueue.main.async(){
                    //Do smth that you need in main thread   
                } 
            }
            else {
                // User Rejected
                print("User Rejected")

                DispatchQueue.main.async(){
                    let alert = UIAlertController(title: "WHY?" , message:  "Camera it is the main feature of our application", preferredStyle: .alert)
                    let action = UIAlertAction(title: "Ok", style: .cancel, handler: nil)
                    alert.addAction(action)
                    self?.present(alert, animated: true, completion: nil)  
                } 
            }
        });
    }
}
}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If you want to save the photo you just need to call `UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum` and pass image object to it in your existing code

Sample code

```
    func capture(_ captureOutput: AVCapturePhotoOutput,  didFinishProcessingPhotoSampleBuffer photoSampleBuffer: CMSampleBuffer?,  previewPhotoSampleBuffer: CMSampleBuffer?, resolvedSettings:  AVCaptureResolvedPhotoSettings, bracketSettings:   AVCaptureBracketedStillImageSettings?, error: Error?) {

        if let error = error {
            print("error occure : \(error.localizedDescription)")
        }

        if  let sampleBuffer = photoSampleBuffer,
            let previewBuffer = previewPhotoSampleBuffer,
            let dataImage =  AVCapturePhotoOutput.jpegPhotoDataRepresentation(forJPEGSampleBuffer:  sampleBuffer, previewPhotoSampleBuffer: previewBuffer) {
            print(UIImage(data: dataImage)?.size as Any)

            let dataProvider = CGDataProvider(data: dataImage as CFData)
            let cgImageRef: CGImage! = CGImage(jpegDataProviderSource: dataProvider!, decode: nil, shouldInterpolate: true, intent: .defaultIntent)
            let image = UIImage(cgImage: cgImageRef, scale: 1.0, orientation: UIImageOrientation.right)

            self.capturedImage.image = image

            //Add: Save image object to photo album
//            UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(image, nil, nil, nil) //
            UIImageWriteToSavedPhotosAlbum(image, self, #selector(self.image(_:didFinishSavingWithError:contextInfo:)), nil)
        } else {
            print("some error here")
        }
    }

    func image(_ image: UIImage, didFinishSavingWithError error: NSError?, contextInfo: UnsafeRawPointer) {
        if let error = error {
            // we got back an error!
            let ac = UIAlertController(title: "Save error", message: error.localizedDescription, preferredStyle: .alert)
            ac.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default))
            present(ac, animated: true)
        } else {
            let ac = UIAlertController(title: "Image Saved!", message: "Your image has been saved to your photos.", preferredStyle: .alert)
            ac.addAction(UIAlertAction(title: "OK", style: .default))
            present(ac, animated: true)
        }
    }
```

I have added the comment above the line which you need to add in your code.